# RateLimit and ibmmq module Node.js

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq, rate-limiting

I'm using ibmmq module https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs.

I am trying to make an application which will get one message from a queue every 500ms.
There is an option getLoopPollTimeMs, but it works when there is no messages in the queue and then they comes.

I've tried to use limiter https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter

```
mq.Get(openQueue.ref as mq.MQObject, mqmd, gmo, await this.getCB.bind(this))
    
async getCB(...) {
const remainingMessages = await this.limiter.removeTokens(1);
...
}
```

So the application reads a message from the queue and processes it.
And in the same time it reads all other messages and wait for the limiter to process because of the asynchronous callback.
But I need it to read the next message only when the previous one is processed.
I've tryed GetSync, but limiter works absolutley incorrect and when it's sync other processes in the application stop working.

How can I get only one message from the queue? Is it the only way if I `mq.GetDone(hObj);` every time in `getCB` and then connect with `mq.Get` to the queue again in `setInterval`? Any advices?

Upd: The way with mq.GetDone(hObj) isn't working. The application reads one message, processes it, and then it reads the second message from the queue and falls with mistake

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Napi::Error'
  what():  GetDone: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_HOBJ_ERROR [2019]
Aborted
```

The queue is closed, but getCB is still working.

Comment: Did you try any of the tuning parameters? See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs and lines 196-202 of https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/148b70db036c80f442adb34769d5d239a6f05b65/lib/mqi.js#L575

Comment: Yeah! That's it! Combination of  mq.setTuningParameters({getLoopDelayTimeMs: 2000, maxConsecutiveGets: 1}) - 1 message in 2 seconds. Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, its possible to use tuning parameters, see https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs and line 196-202 of https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/148b70db036c80f442adb34769d5d239a6f05b65/lib/mqi.js#L575

Again as per the comments you could use a combination of

```js
 mq.setTuningParameters({getLoopDelayTimeMs: 2000, maxConsecutiveGets: 1})
```

for a throttle limit of 1 message in 2 seconds.